# Store file in the azure storage account which is network restricted

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

we have one azure storage account which is network restricted. We are saving a file from the runbook but seems it is failing. Any thoughts?

```
$fileshare ='TestStorage'

#Map to the reports BLOB context
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $acctKey
      
$csvTable | Export-CSV $LogFileName -NoTypeInformation

#Copy the file to the storage account : For the .csv file
Set-AzureStorageFileContent –Share $fileshare –Source $LogFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Private link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/how-to/private-link-security) between your Runbook and a subnet approved by your storage account (or a new subnet).

You can also enable and disable on-demand public access from your Runbook.

Note: The private link is not free.